# GraphQL-tag always uses default value

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma-graphql

Can anyone explain me why my graphQL query always uses default values even if I specified my own value for this argument?

```js
const FEED_QUERY2 = gql`
    query FEED_QUERY2($category : String = "NoPosts")
    {
        feed2(filter:  $category ) {
            blogposts {
                id
                name
                categories {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

And am calling my query like this

```js
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
.
.
.
const category_string = "Python";
<Query query={FEED_QUERY2} category={category_string}>
```

Comment: props are not variables

Comment: old syntax/usage in old docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/queries/#receiving-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category` is not a valid prop for the `Query` component. The props available on the component are shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-components/#query) in the docs. If you want to pass variables to your query, you should use the `variables` prop.

```
<Query query={FEED_QUERY2} variables={{category: category_string}}>
```